# Tools to help manage sets of multiple versions of executables on Linux?

Tags: linux, unix

We are in a networked Linux environment and what I'm looking for is a FOSS or generic system level method for managing what versions of executables and libraries get used, per session. The executables would preferably be installed on the network. The executables will be in-house tools and installs of commercial packages like Houdini, Maya and Nuke.

The need for this is that we'd prefer to have multiple versions of the software installed and available for the artists but there needs to be an easy way to select which version to use. As an added benefit, I'd like to be able to track the version of software used to generate a given output as metadata. I've worked at studios that did this successfully but I was not 100% up to speed on how it was achieved.  Every executable in a given set was assigned a single uber version for the set. That way, the "approved packages" of the studio tools were all collapsed into a single package of tools that were known to work together.

Due to the way they install, some programs make setting this up easy (It's as simple as adding their install directories to $PATH). Other programs don't make it quite so easy. I'm particularly worried about how to handle the libraries a program might install. What's needed is a generic access method I can use to wrap everything into a clean front end.

Does anyone know of such a system available in the wild or am I going to have to implement it from scratch?  Google hasn't been very helpful in finding a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the `chroot` manpages if that cmould be a solution.

Comment: chroot is a more heavy handed than what I had in mind.  With chroot I'd lose access to the bulk of the OS and system and I'd need to re-implimented it in the jail to use it.  I was thinking more along the lines of a set of symbolic links or shell scripts to set environment variables which selected the software version "sets". What I'm looking for is any existant toolset to help impliment and manage such a system.

Comment: Then it's indeed better to use a combination of PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to the right values before starting the programs.

Answer (score 0):

There is [eselect](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/eselect/) . I have only used it on funtoo(offspring of gentoo) but it seems to be doing what you need. It is also written entirely in BASH, so it should be quite possible to port to other distros.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "modules" system at http://modules.sourceforge.net/ ; it's quite widely used in HPC.